# dev c. failed to execute .exe error 193: %1 not a valid win32 application

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

so I was trying to test run my dev c++ as usual and it said failed to execute location/name.exe error 193: %1 is not a valid win 32 application. I have not used the compiler for anything complex yet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14
int main()
{
    int r      = 3;

    float area = PI*pow(r,2);

    printf("the area of the circle is %f",area);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Dev c++ GCC (MinGW) compiler.

it compiles properly but when I try to run, it get this error message

Failed to execute "C:\Users\SIM JONES NIGL TD\Desktop\c language\areaofcircle2.exe":
Error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Press any key to continue

Comment: Show what compiler you have you used and the command line etc.

Comment: I don't know that IDE. But try to create a new win32 console project, or rebuild the existing project, nothing wrong with the code itself...

Comment: sorry I saw this late I will try it now and send feed back.

Answer (score 9):

I just experienced this problem and I noticed that if you just save your programs in a folder containing no spaces, it works. My default folder was set to `My Documents` so I made a folder in my `F:` drive named `programs` and saved the programs in it and then compiled them. I didn't experience this error then.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AlLelopath Looks like a perfect answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem save the cpp file in a folder with no spaces.  For example

> Older path c:/Users/jorge santos/programa1.cpp
>
> New path c:/Users/jorgesantos/programa1.cpp

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did it solve the problem? because it did for me. If the problem still persists kindly send me the error here

Comment: not a solution. The question is why Dev has a problem with spaces in paths when it didn't use to?

Comment: @SomeStudent Many old outdated programs have this limitation. The real solution is to use modern programs on your new platform. If you don't, then you need to work around the problems, like in this case, don't use paths containing spaces

Comment: @TedLyngmo I got confused, I thought you wrote this comment  under the question I asked. Anyway I have this issue but just because I installed Visual Studio. Dev dodn't have this problem before. The correlation is certain.

Comment: @SomeStudent Dev C++ may have had this issue at one point in time and since this question is pretty old it's quite possible that the people who answered this question actually used an old version of Dev C++. What version do you use? You never stated that in your question. Perhaps VS installed something that is picked up (via the PATH or otherwise) by Dev C++ - but it helps to know which version we're talking about.