# Dev C++ failed to execute error 193 %1 is not a valid win32 application | C Programming

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ide, dev-c++

[image]I just wrote a basic c program to run but compiler prompts the error (see attached image). I have installed Dev-C++ before where I did C++ Programming. But when I wrote C code it prompts  error I have deleted it & reinstalled the Dev-C++ again but couldn't run please help.
IDE Version: 5.11

Comment: Is the path to the c project different from the c++ one? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40188810/2513200, answers there indicate this IDE seems to have a problem with spaces in pathnames, for example.

Comment: Yeah tried that too still not working

Comment: Where is attached image ?

Comment: Attached now please review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must choose the right Project configuration (C project):

[image]

Remarque : you must have a project path without space. Exemple : `C:\Ali\untiled\untiled.c`

Comment: tried this and result is windows 10 defender blocking it with error as: Category: Torjan Details: This program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker

Comment: @AliAsadullahShah I dont know what you are doing in your program (but according to the post nothing special), but your antivirus considers it as a virus, you must add the executable to the trusted list of your antivirus.

Comment: @AliAsadullahShah if you have had an alert from your antivirus, this means that you have passed the compilation phase. that you have successfully generated an ".exe" and that you are now in the execution phase.

Comment: I've allowed in Windows Defender but problem persist please see the image I have added now in question. Looking forward to hear solution....still figuring out

Comment: Can you try to create this project in a directory without space. Example : C:\Ali\untiled\untiled.c